# Create POST request, using Java RestAssured, returns status code 422

Tags: java, junit, rest-assured

I have Ubuntu server instance on Windows 10. I have application, which is running on localhost on Ubuntu.
When I create request on Ubuntu terminal:

```
curl http://localhost:8000/test \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" \
    -H "Authorization: Basic cJJdlJ26p62JG23j34==" \
    -d '{
    "test": {
      "id": "564624232443234",
      "type": "book"
    }
}'
```

It works and insert into database.

When I have JUnit test in Eclipse with same JSON values above:

```
public class Test extends Connection {
.......

    @Test
    public void test_Insert() {
        Map<Object, String> mapRequest = new HashMap<>();
        mapRequest.put("id", "564624232443234");
        mapRequest.put("type", "book");

        given().
            contentType(ContentType.JSON).  
            header("Authorization", "Basic "+"cJJdlJ26p62JG23j34==").
            body(mapRequest).
        when().
            post("test").
        then().
            statusCode(200);

    }
```

It doesn't work. Returns me:

> java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
>   Expected status code <200> but was <422>.

If I only ping the server like below, the response is correct (200).

```
    @Test
    public void basicPingTest() {
        given().when().get("/").then().statusCode(200);
    }
```

Any ideas of the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't send the same request by curl and by RestAssured.
Curl:

```json
{
    "test": {
        "id": "564624232443234",
        "type": "book"
    }
}
```

Restassured:

```json
{
    "id": "564624232443234",
    "type": "book"
}
```

Add the map as `test` object

```
public class Test extends Connection {
.......

    @Test
    public void test_Insert() {
        Map<Object, String> mapRequest = new HashMap<>();
        mapRequest.put("id", "564624232443234");
        mapRequest.put("type", "book");

        given().
            contentType(ContentType.JSON).  
            header("Authorization", "Basic "+"cJJdlJ26p62JG23j34==").
            body(Collections.singletonMap("test",mapRequest)).
        when().
            post("test").
        then().
            statusCode(200);

    }
}
```